# How do I check whether my WDM/KMDF driver uses the retpoline fix?

Tags: kmdf, spectre, windows-driver

I have developed several WDM/KMDF Windows drivers. I compiled the sys with a recent version of Visual Studio 2022 and WDK 10.0.22621.0.

After doing the attestation test signing at the Microsoft Partner Center, in the report I see a message that the drivers do not contain the retpoline fix (Spectre mitigation).

I uploaded multiple WDM/KMDF drivers in one package and want to know which one does not have the repoline fix. How can I check this?